# Find the residue at $z=-2$ for $g(z) = \frac{\psi(-z)}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the residue at $z=-2$ for

$$g(z) = \frac{\psi(-z)}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$$

I know that:

$$\psi(z+1) = -\gamma - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\zeta(k+1)z^k$$

Let $z \to -1 - z$ to get:

$$\psi(-z) = -\gamma - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta(k+1)(z+1)^k$$

therefore we divide by the other part to get:

$$\frac{\psi(-z)}{(z+1)(z+2)^3} = -\frac{\gamma}{(z+1)(z+2)^3} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(k+1)(z+1)^{k-1}}{(z+2)^3}$$

I have to somehow get the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z+2}$ because I want to evaluate the residue of

$g(z)$ at $z=-2$

The problem is I cant ever get a factor of $\frac{1}{z+2}$ what should I do?

Comment: Write $(z+1)^k=((z+2)-1)^k$ and use the binomial theorem...

Comment: Can you show me how to do that for a general $k$? please?

Comment: the point is, that you only need it here until $k=3$ because as you already mentioned only the term with $1/(z+2)$ is interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\psi(z)$ is regular over $\Re(z)>0$, hence $z=-2$ is a triple pole for $g(z)$. This gives:
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(g(z),z=-2\right)= \frac{1}{2}\left.\frac{d^2}{dz^2} (z+2)^3 g(z)\right|_{z=-2}=\frac{1}{2}\left.\frac{d^2}{dz^2} \frac{\psi(-z)}{z+1}\right|_{z=-2}\tag{1}$$
so:
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(g(z),z=-2\right)=\left.\frac{\psi(-z)}{(1+z)^3}+\frac{ \psi'(-z)}{(1+z)^2}+\frac{\psi''(-z)}{2(1+z)}\right|_{z=-2} = -\psi(2)+\psi'(2)-\frac{\psi''(2)}{2}$$
leading to:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\operatorname{Res}\left(g(z),z=-2\right)&=& -(1-\gamma)+\left(1-\zeta(2)\right)-\frac{\psi''(2)}{2}\\&=&\gamma-\zeta(2)+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+2)^3}\\&=&\color{red}{\gamma-\zeta(2)+\zeta(3)-1}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I am trying to avoid the limit approach. Thanks anyway!This derivative method is **too cumbersome** without a calculator. How did you calculate $\psi"(2)$ without a calculator?

Comment: @Amad27: Since for any $z$ in the right halfplane $$\psi'(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+z)^2},$$ it follows that $$\psi''(z)=-2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+z)^3},$$ hence $\psi''$ at the positive integers simply depends on $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: @Amad27: Anyway, when dealing with a triple pole, to avoid derivatives is a mere dream. I think this method is way faster then rearranging the series for $\psi(z)$ through geometric series expansions.

Comment: I will accept the answer because this is a nice method but otherwise, we could use the taylor series representation for $\psi(z + 1)$

Comment: With this series:

$$\psi(-z) = -\gamma - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta(k+1)(z+1)^k$$

First we divide by our part:

$$\frac{\psi(-z)}{(z+1)(z+2)^3} = -\frac{\gamma}{(z+1)(z+2)^3} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(k+1)(z+1)^{k-1}}{(z+2)^3}$$

We see (z+1)=((z+2) - 1) And then take this to the third power we get a factor of $(z+2)^2$ somewhere.

We have to let $k=3$ to get:

$$... + \frac{\zeta(4)}{(z+2)} + ...$$

But this gives the incorrect coefficient?

Comment: @Amad27: Nope, you have to multiply $$\psi(-z)=(1-\gamma)-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(1-\zeta(k+1))z^k$$ and $$\frac{1}{z+1}=-\sum_{k\geq 0}(z+2)^k $$ then compute the coefficient of $(z+2)^2$.

Comment: Why is my approach incorrect?

Comment: @Amad27: because your right hand sides are not power series in the variable $(z+2)$, they have to be rearranged to reach that form.

Comment: It follows from definition though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series

Comment: @Amad27: I was talking about the expansion you gave for $g(z)$. It is not a power series, in that form.

Comment: I thought: $$\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = \sum_{n=1}^{infty} \frac{b_n}{a}$$ ??

Comment: @Amad27: but in this particular case, both $a$ and $b_n$ depend on $z$, and we can extract a residue only from a power series, not from a generic series.

Comment: $b_n$ depends on $n$ not $z$ though?

Comment: If $\sum b_n$ is the Taylor expansion for some function $h(z)$, $b_n$ does depend on $z$. Think about it, I have no time for digging into details you should have studied by yourself before approaching these questions.

Comment: Consider the function $\frac{1}{1-x}$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n-1}$$ Yes okay, for a certain value of $x$ I see what you mean. But at the same time:

$$\frac{x}{1-x} = \sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n}$$ 

We took $x$ inside the sum, we can do the same with $$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}$$ by this logic cant we?

Comment: How about using the traditional definition of the constant $a_n$ given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series

Comment: So, if there are many series representing a function, such a function has many residues in $z=-2$? Nope, the issue is that $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\zeta(n) (z+2)^n (z+1)^{19} $$ *is not* a power series in $(z+2)$, end story.

Comment: Okay. How about the approached used here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101277/sum-n-1-infty-frac1n1n23-using-complex-analysis/1101765#1101765

Comment: @Amad27: I see nothing wrong in that approach. By Cauchy integral formula, we can compute derivatives (like I did) by integrating along a path.

Comment: But he did not consider $f(z)$ completely there. He left out $\frac{1}{(z+1)}$ and what about the other power of (z+2)?

Comment: He was integrating $g(z)$ along a circle centered in the right point. Nothing wrong. By the way, why do you have two accounts?

Comment: So he does not need to consider $\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$ I am using this account because I cannot access my account, this is not a personal computer, I do not want to use my credentials on this machine.

Comment: Jack D' Aurizio, how would you find the residue at a general $n$?

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103957/finding-the-residue-at-z-n

Comment: @Amad27: where are the singularities of $\phi(-z)$? can you prove they are all simple poles?

Comment: Jack, yes because they are only undefined for one part, $\psi(z)$

Comment: Then, since $\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$ is a regular function over $\Re(z)>0$, the residue of $g(z)$ in $z=n$ simply equals the residue of $\psi(-z)$ at $z=n$ times $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}$. This is the reason for using such function to encode the series Marko Riedel solved.

Comment: You are amazing, upvotes * 1 million! but which law or property states this? Ive never seen this definition/

Comment: Assume that $f(z)=g(z)h(z)$, where $g(z)$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ while $h(z)$ has a simple pole in $z_0$. Then $f(z)$ has a simple pole in $z_0$ too, and: $$\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z=z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)(z-z_0) = g(z_0)\lim_{z\to z_0}h(z)(z-z_0) = g(z_0)\operatorname{Res}(h(z),z=z_0)$$ by the definition of residue in a simple pole.

Comment: Obviously, that does not hold anymore if $h(z)$ has a *double* pole or worse in $z_0$.

Comment: Okay. So how do we calculate residue of digamma? 

$$Res = \lim_{z \to n} \psi(-z)(z-n)$$

Somehow, it equals $1$ but I am not sure how. Please only hints, do not give a direct answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Amad27: I just gave you a complete answer in your other question, look at there. It is one, by the way, you're right.

Comment: Ok nice! I used the series representation, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-n}$ is $1$ The question remains, what is the residue of $$\frac{(\psi(-z) + \gamma)^2}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$$ at $z=-2$ I will try it, and post a question later.

Comment: Jack, can you help here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104046/residue-of-frac-psi-z-gamma2z1z23-at-z-n I did some work but I am not sure how to proceed with the other part?

Comment: I cant figure out the residue at $z=-2$ can you help? I tried the limit way but the square creates an issue. What should I do?

Comment: I just remarked that my lemma works for simple poles, but obviously when introducing a square such a function has a *double* pole in $z=n\geq 0$. Do you want also the residue in $z=-2$? In such a case the numerator is a holomorphic function and the remaining part has a triple pole. Multiply by $(z+2)^3$ and differentiate twice. It should be clear now.

Comment: Differentiation is insanely hard.

Comment: In such a case I cannot help you.

Comment: Actually, the lemma you stated should work for all. Robjohn did the same: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081800/explanation-for-summation-complex-analysis-method